# Is it ok to wash silk with baby wash and shampoo (instead of just baby shampoo)

Tags: clothing

I've always washed silk with baby shampoo, but it seems most brands are now wash and shampoo.  Are these still ok to use for cleaning silk?

Comment: What is the difference between "baby wash and shampoo" and "baby shampoo"? Is it marketing? So that you use the product to wash the whole baby, and not just their hair?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Nathan, Welcome to Lifehacks. Don't forget to visit [Tour] and [Help] to find out how to get more from our site. We hope you enjoy yourself here sharing your knowledge and ingenuity. For the effort, you'll sport a badge and get a 'rep' point. I support @WeatherVane who suggests simple 'Marketing' seeking a broader market is behind the labeling change. My online searches support this. Short answer: Yes. Good luck